# How to import a Javascript file to Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, nuxt.js

Im trying to import the following javascript files from a website template to my project. Im not sure where the problem lies.

Im interested to convert this website template to a nuxt.js project.

From what i could gather i need to add

`plugins: [
    '~plugins/axios',
    '~plugins/script.js',
    '~plugins/core.min.js',
    '~plugins/html5shiv.min.js',
    '~plugins/pointer-events.min.js',
  ],`

to the **nuxt.config.js** file.

The projects compiles perfectly but i get the following error:

`Nuxt.js Error:`

`ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`

```
at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (plugins/script.js:8:16)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap f7e9adeb2d4cb66ad75c:25:0)
at Object.<anonymous> (.nuxt/index.js:27:14)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap f7e9adeb2d4cb66ad75c:25:0)
at Object.<anonymous> (server-bundle.js:1366:65)
at __webpack_require__ (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap f7e9adeb2d4cb66ad75c:25:0)
at server-bundle.js:95:18
at Object.<anonymous> (server-bundle.js:98:10)
at evaluateModule (/Users/---/------/projects/---/website-try4/website/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:5820:21)
at /Users/-----/------/projects/-----/website-try4/website/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:5878:18
at /Users/-----/----/projects/-----/website-try4/website/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:5870:14
at Nuxt.renderToString (/Users/----/---/projects/----/website-try4/website/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:6022:9)
at P (/Users/---/---/projects/---/website-try4/website/node_modules/pify/index.js:49:6)
at Nuxt.<anonymous> (/Users/---/---/projects/---/website-try4/website/node_modules/pify/index.js:11:9)
at Nuxt.ret [as renderToString] (/Users/--/---/projects/---/website-try4/website/node_modules/pify/index.js:72:32)
at Nuxt._callee2$ (/Users/---/---/projects/---/website-try4/website/node_modules/nuxt/dist/nuxt.js:2076:25)`
```

I can provide more information if you need.

What else should I be doing to import these Javascript files properly?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Not all javascript files should be included through plugins in the nuxt.config.js.
Only Vue plugins should.

The error you get is because you want to execute client side code on the server and NodeJS (unlike a browser) doesn't have a navigator property.

To fix this:
Try to use axios only on places you need it (through an import or require)
*example:*
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware

Put the other scripts in your head or at the bottom of your body tag in the **app.html**
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#document

*To extend the html template, create a app.html at the root of your project. The default template is:*

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
    <head>
        {{ HEAD }}
    </head>
    <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
      {{ APP }}
    </body>
  </html>
```